# How to prevent in app purchase pirating

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, jailbreak

I am aware that with Jailbreaking, there are tools such as APCrack or iAP Cracker that are able to purchase in-app purchases without paying.

How would I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have a server component that you can withhold from the client if your server contacts [Apple's App Store to verify the receipt](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1) and the verification fails.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and let you know how it goes

Comment: How about android? Google play

Comment: @NikAhmadZainalddin you should ask that in a new question as this one specific related to iOS.